# The existence of an orthonormal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $U$ be an orthonormal matrix. The dimension of $U$ is equal to $n \times n$. The first row of $U$ has the following form:
$$\bigg( \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}, \ldots , \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \bigg). \tag{1}$$
How can I prove that $U$ with property (1) exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take your row vector (call it $v_1$) and extend this set to a basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then orthonormalize this basis, (using Gram-Schmidt), obtaining {$v_1, \dots, v_n$}. Then, the matrix U such that its jth row is $v_j$ is an orthonormal matrix.

Answer (score 2):

$u:=(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}},\ldots,\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}})$ is a unit vector in your vector space. You can extend it to a basis $\{u,v_{2},\ldots,v_{n}\}$ of $V$ and then apply the Gram-Schmidt algorithm on this basis to obtain an orthonormal basis: $\{e_{1},e_{2},\ldots,e_{n}\}$ of $V$, where $e_{1}=u$. The matrix with rows $e_{1},\ldots e_{n}$ will then be a unitary matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the vectors $v_1=e_1+\dots+e_n$, $v_i=e_i$ for $i=2,\dots,n$ and apply Gram-Schmidt to them. Then you obtain an orthonormal basis whose first vector is $(e_1+\dots+e_n)/\sqrt n$, which is precisely the vector you want.

Comment: Can the downvoter explain please? This answer is correct and was also the first to be posted